# Heap errors with using vector in C++ for loop?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

Are there any known issues with heap corruption with declaring and using a vector inside a for loop? For instance doing this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
   std::vector<int> vec;
   for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
      vec.push_back(0); //-Initialize
   }
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: Assuming you've parametrised `std::vector<T>` with something sensible, then it's fine.

Comment: For heap errors and a vector, I would assume you are using `vec[x]` where `x` is not a valid index.  Replace your `[x]` with `.at(x)`, or use asserts to help find the problem.

Comment: Are you saying that you are actually experiencing the heap corruption? If so, this might be caused by a memory corruption in entirely different part of the program. The snippet you have shown us looks fine.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, I don't have that issue. I am using vec[x] later; but I bail out with an error if x is invalid.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: Even with you asserting that it is valid: given the code you have shown it is _still_ my best guess as to the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

No, that's fine, but the same effect can be obtained using

```
std::vector<int> vec(3,0)
```

instead of the second loop.